# How do I get a contact's sales from Salesforce using the API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, salesforce

I'm looking through the API for Salesforce and trying to get familiar with it for a project I'll be working on.

Everything looks fine, I can get a Contact, a Case, an Event, a Lead, etc.

The only thing I don't see in the API is a way to get the actual sales data for a contact. I figured it would be one of the main methods available, but I can't find anything about it.

I don't know if there's a different name for a Sale object, or if I have to use some other method. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [salesforce schema](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_erd_majors.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_erd_majors.htm|SkinName=webhelp) for Sales objects and similarly the [full listing of all standard objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_erd_majors.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_erd_majors.htm|SkinName=webhelp)? There's quite a lot in there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SalesForce refers to sales data as an [Opportunity](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm#topic-title). Opportunities move through stages. To tell if an Opportunity has been converted to a sale you can check Opportunity.IsWon field.

As you can see [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm), you can find opportunities for a contact using the many-to-many OpportunityContactRole table. (OpportunityContactRole.ContactId <-> Opportunity.Id).

Comment: Edit was to correct this line: (OpportunityContactRole.ContactId <-> OpportunityContactRole.ContactId)